# get an element Y position relative to the document top

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get an element Y position relative to the document top.

I have tried this :

```
function initScroll() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.full-module__img').forEach(function (module) {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
            let distFromTopViewport = module.getBoundingClientRect().top;
            console.log(distFromTopViewport + scrollY);
        });
    })
}
```

It works fine, but since it is an event listener, it comes as long as I scroll, yet I want it once.

Then If I do this, It return a hazardous value:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.full-module__img').forEach(function (module) {
        let distFromTopViewport = module.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        console.log(distFromTopViewport + scrollY);
    })
}
```

I **just want the distance of the elem from the top of the document**. I must have the wrong solution…

**EDIT : I have tried this too:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.full-module__img').forEach(function (module) {
        let distFromTopViewport = module.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        console.log(distFromTopViewport + window.pageYOffset);
})
```

But it renders a wrong value (it renders 522 and It should be 1300 something). I must be wrong again.

Is there anyone that can help me? Thanks a lot :)

PS: I have checked the Offset method with Jquery but I'm trying to stay with full Vanilla JS…

Comment: What is the event in which you only want it once, the page load or some threshold distance?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question… sorry !  I want that on load, the distance is calculated

Answer (score 2):

You was right with `element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset`. this is the correct value.

Comment: However it doesn't work :/ It renders a different value if I reload after scroll. And the value doesnt make any sense…

Comment: I tried with and event listener on scroll and it works. However I cannot use this since I want it once…

Comment: I tried it also and the value is not change after scroll. What do you mean "after reload page"? a page refresh?

Comment: If I don't use an event trigger onscroll, the value isn't correct. It renders 500 and it should be 1300. If I set it with an even trigger onscroll, the value is correct BUT I don't want that since I want a const variable that will not change when I scroll.

Comment: In fact I want that ONCE after the page load the distance is calculated and the value never change or is never tested again

Comment: OK... the problem is not in this piece of code. maybe this code is executed too early so the element is not in his correct position... maybe other elements are added to the page after the page loaded.. I dont know, anyway this piece of code is good.

Comment: Hey ! Sorry I found the problem. I have using that code on a sticky element and apparently It mess with the javascript value. I used it with the parentElem and everything works fine ! :D

Answer (score 0):

I have using that code on a sticky element and apparently It mess with the javascript value. I used it with the parentElem and everything works fine